# Generalization of a Folland Proposition 2.12

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The Proposition $2.12$ of "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications" says that: Let $(X, \cal M, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(X, \cal \overline M, \overline \mu)$ be its completion. If $f$ is a $\cal \overline M-$measure function on $X$, there is a $\cal M-$ measure function $g$ on s.t. $f=g$ $\overline \mu-$a.e.

My question is: Can we find a function $g$ which is $\cal M-$measure and $f = g$ $\mu-$a.e.

My attempt: I was trying to solve as a corollary of the Proposition. Let $M \in \cal \overline M$ s.t. $\overline \mu (X\setminus M) = 0$ and $f = g$ in $M$. Writing $M = A \cup Z_1$ where $A \in \cal M$ and $Z_1$ is $\mu-$null, we have that $ A \subset M$, so $f=g$ in $A$, but I can't ensure that $\mu(X\setminus A) = 0$.

By the other side, $X\setminus M = B \cup Z_2$ where $B \in \cal M$ and $Z_2$ is $\mu-$null, in this case we have $\mu (B) = \overline \mu (X\setminus M) = 0$, but I can't ensure that $f=g$ in $X\setminus B$.

I appreciate any hints, thank you.

Comment: You may want to simply remind yourself what the measure completion is and how it's constructed.